# reset fck editor values yii

Tags: yii

I am using yii framework and i have fck editor in form. If i click reset button all the fields in the form get empty but the editor doesn't. This is the code for fck editor

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.fckeditor.FCKEditorWidget',array(
    "model"=>$model,                # Data-Model
    "attribute"=>'content',         # Attribute in the Data-Model
    "height"=>'400px',
    "width"=>'100%',

    "fckeditor"=>Yii::app()->basePath."/../fckeditor/fckeditor.php",
                                    # Path to fckeditor.php
    "fckBasePath"=>Yii::app()->baseUrl."/fckeditor/",
                                    # Relative Path to the Editor (from Web-Root)
    "config" => array("EditorAreaCSS"=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/index.css',),
                                    # Additional Parameters
```

How can i do that?

Comment: seems it's not an yii problem but fckeditor, maybe setting are stored in cookies?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK FCKEditor (and any other similar) is based on simple textbox (HTML element textarea).

If you're using jQuery, I would consider adding a simple piece of code to onDocumentReady function in the view that is generated after reset of the form (or directly to the Reset Button's onClick code, if you're not reloading page after reset). In this code I would simply force field that is used as base for FCKEditor to make sure it is empty.

Something like this:

```
$('#editor').val('');
```

Written from memory, not tested though.